# How to effectively gitignore client/public/bundle.js and client/public/bundle.js.LICENSE.txt?

Tags: git, github, gitignore

From my project base directory (where .gitignore is located), I want to git ignore two files,

```
client/public/bundle.js
client/public/bundle.js.LICENSE.txt
```

I have tried, `**/bundle.js`, `client/public/bundle.js`, but it is not working. do I need to clear the git cache in the project, as well as delete the file if it exists upstream/remote?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Entries in a `.gitignore` file have no effect on files that are already tracked.  If you want to ignore the files, then you need to remove them with `git rm --cached` so that Git doesn't track them.  This is [outlined in the Git FAQ](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#files-in-gitignore-are-tracked).

If your goal is to keep the files tracked but ignore changes to them, [that isn't possible](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#ignore-tracked-files).  There are alternative solutions that you can adopt described in that FAQ entry.

Answer (score 2):

[bk2204's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66946244/1256452) about removing the existing tracked files is the correct answer.  (This is because `.gitignore` does not really mean *ignore* these files.  Instead, it means *do not complain about them being untracked, and do not automatically add them to tracked files when using an en-masse "add many files now" operation*.  If the files are already tracked–which has a technical definition—having their names in `.gitignore` has no effect.)  Here, I want to add a (long!) side remark about [Asif Kamran Malick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66946279/1256452) about anchoring path names with leading slashes.

In a `.gitignore` file, there are several different things you can do with slashes.  A *trailing* slash tells Git that the pattern on this line is that for a *directory:*

```
dir/
```

or:

```
path/to/dir/
```

will cause Git to "ignore" (i.e., not complain about, and not add) the *directory* `dir` or `path/to/dir`.  But in fact Git never adds a *directory*, so this is even more misleading than the idea that these files might be "ignored" (rather than not-complained-about and not-automatically-added).  It really gives Git permission to *not look inside the directory*.  The trailing slash tells Git: *only do this if it really **is** a directory*, so that:

```
foo/bar/
```

will not look inside `foo/bar/`, but *will* complain about and/or auto-add a *file* named `foo/bar`, if present.

So this is what a trailing slash does.  [The gitignore documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) has been improved and now says:

> - If there is a separator at the end of the pattern then the pattern will only match directories, otherwise the pattern can match both files and directories.

In the old days, it talked about "removing" the trailing slash for a particular purpose, which was very confusing.

Besides the *trailing* slash, though, you can have:

- a leading slash, such as `/filename`, and/or
- an *embedded* slash, such as `dir/file`.

A string like `/path/file` has both.

*Either* of these tells Git that this path must match in *this directory*.  That is, if we have a directory containing `file` and `subdir/file`, and a `.gitignore` reading:

```
/file
```

this matches only the file named `file` in *this* directory, not `subdir/file`.  With *no* slashes, it matches *both* and will "ignore" (not-complain-about, avoid-auto-adding) both `file` and `subdir/file`.

In the OP's case, the files—named from the root anyway—are named `client/public/bundle.js` and `client/public/bundle.js.LICENSE.txt`.  No matter how we spell the files—with or without a leading slash—there is at least one *embedded* slash.  In fact, there are always *two* embedded slashes here.  So these files are already anchored.

We could create a `.gitignore` file in the `client/` directory; here, we could list either:

```
public/bundle.js
public/bundle.js.LICENSE.txt
```

or the same two names with a leading slash, and either way that would still match only those files.  But if we created a `.gitignore` file inside `client/public`, we would need to write:

```
/bundle.js
/bundle.js.LICENSE.txt
```

if we wish to have Git not-complain-about and not-auto-add those files *at this level*, but still complain about and/or auto-add a file named `subdir/bundle.js` at this level.  That is, if `client/public/subdir/bundle.js` should be complained-about and not-skipped-by-en-masse-add (i.e., not *ignored*), we would need anchored names in a `.gitignore` in this directory.

One can ignore this particular complication and always anchor all names regardless of whether they're already anchored due to embedded slashes.  It's not harmful, it just has no effect when they already have an embedded slash.  A *trailing* slash does not count as an embedded slash, though!

Comment: This indeed helps.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned about base directory, you need to prepend a forward slash **" / "** for patterns to match the root.

```
/client/public/bundle.js
/client/public/bundle.js.LICENSE.txt
```

If those files are already tracked by git then you need to remove them with `git rm --cached <file-path>`

Comment: This isn't *quite* right for a somewhat complicated reason, but it doesn't hurt to anchor the paths with a leading slash in this case.

Comment: Thank you so much. I would definitely like to learn about the issue.